# Automatic spaces between "aligned" environments

Tags: spacing, equations, align, vertical-spacing

I was doing this:

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\jot}{1ex}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $
        \begin{aligned}[t]
               u'=(\delta+i\omega) \Rightarrow u
            &= Ae^{(\delta+i\omega)t} \\
            &= Ae^{\delta t}e^{i\omega t} \\
            &= Ae^{\delta t}(\cos{\omega t}+i\sin{\omega t}) \\
        \end{aligned} \\
        \begin{aligned}
            \textrm{Re}\{u\}=Ae^{\delta t}\cos{\omega t}
        \end{aligned}
          $
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and I realized that I wanted more space between the last two lines. So I added `[1ex]` after the `\\` between the `\end{aligned}` and `\begin{aligned}` and that gave me the spacing I wanted. I was wondering if there was a way to make this spacing automatic since I'm going to have to do this a lot.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: You have to have some markup to force a linebreak (or start a new paragraph) as by default  two aligned will come side-by-side not one above the other. If `\\[1ex]`  is two much to type  use `\nl` with `\newcommand\nl{\\[1ex]}` for example.

Comment: for the second one there is no alignment at all so you could remove `\begin{aligned}` and `\end{aligned}`

Comment: I don't see why the second one needs to be in the same math environment at all. I guess the first one is using `aligned` because it needs to be inline math to align with the enumerate item. But the second one could be put in a separate `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}` display math environment, which would have space before it, couldn't it?